# Simulating Probability Distributions

Tags: probability-distributions

We have the following cumulative distribution function:

$$
F(x) = 
\begin{cases}
0 & x < 0 \\
x^2/9 & 0 \le x \le 3 \\
1 & x > 3
\end{cases}
$$

To find $X$ in terms of $U \sim \mathrm{Uniform}[0, 1]$:

$$ F^{-1}(u)=\min\{x: F(x) \ge u\}=\min\{x: x^2/9 \ge u\}=\min\{x: x \ge 3 \sqrt{u}\}=3\sqrt{u}$$

$$X =F^{-1}(U)=3\sqrt{U}$$

However suppose now that:

$$
F(x) = 
\begin{cases}
0 & x < 1 \\
x^2/9 & 1 \le x \le 3 \\
1 & x > 3
\end{cases}
$$

Following the same steps as above, we would have:

$$ X =F^{-1}(U)=3\sqrt{U}$$

This doesn't seem right since the steps don't seem to take into the account the different range of values for $x$. I'd like to know what the correct approach is.

Comment: Your second function isn't continuous so can't be a cumulative distribution..

Comment: @IanMiller You're right, I didn't notice that. What if the ranges for the second function were $x \lt 0$, $0 \le x \lt 4$ and $x  \gt 4$?

Comment: Then the cumulative probability between 3 and 4 would be greater than 1... and you'd have a discontinuity at 4.

Comment: CDFs can, and often are, discontinuous (on the left).

Comment: @Did, that's right. I checked and CDF's can be only right continuous. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not correct.

Your second distribution has two parts: a discrete part with 
$$
P(X=1) = F(1) - \lim_{x\to1^-} F(x) = 1/9 - 0 =\frac19
$$ 
and a continuous part with 
$$
P(X>1) = 1 - P(X \le 1) = 1 - P(X = 1) = \frac89.
$$

The continuous part is uniform on $(1,3)$ only given $X>1$, so that 
$$
P\big(X<x\big|X>1\big)
= \frac{P(1<X<x)}{P(X>1)}\mathbb1(x>1)
= \frac{F(x)-F(1)}{1-F(1)}\mathbb1(x>1)
= \frac{x^2/9-1/9}{8/9}\mathbb1(1<x<3)
= \frac{x^2-1}{8}\mathbb1(1<x<3).
$$

To actually generate a variate from that second distribution, you would have to consider
$$
X = \max\{1, 3\sqrt{U}\} =
\begin{cases}
1, &\text{if $U<1/9$}\\
F^{-1}(U) = 3\sqrt{U}, &\text{if $U>1/9$.}
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: In the continuous part, you had $P(X>1) = P(X \le 1)$. Did you mean $P(X > 1) = 1 - P(X \le 1)$ instead?

Comment: @user137481 that's right, thanks!